# Windows 10 SDK Check WPF GPU Rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, gpu

I haven't had the need to check this for a while and it seems I'm out of the loop.

Back in the [Windows 7 SDK the WPF Performance Suite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa969767(v=vs.110).aspx#visual_profiler) offered the ability to run an application and have it detail which portions of the UI are being rendered by the GPU by tinting bits of the UI.

The new Windows 10 SDK has The Performance Toolkit which in comparison seems impregnable in it's set up complexity and doesn't seem to offer this functionality anymore and I cannot find much documentation on it's use online.

Does anyone know if this ability still exists and how to configure the toolkit to do this?

Comment: Did you try the Performance Profiler in Visual Studio? You will find it under Debug->Performance Profiler.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't show this visually like the old tools used too.  I can see it using the GPU but I can't see the exact bits of the UI that is or isn't GPU accelerated.